# how do i fix this name is not defined error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def us_30():
    page = session.get('https://www.investing.com/indices/us-30-technical')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    summary = soup.find(id="techStudiesInnerWrap")
    print(summary.div.text)
    name = soup.find("td", class_="first left symbol", string="RSI(14)")
    value = name.find_next('td')
    action = value.find_next('td')
    print(f"Name: {name.text}. Value:{value.text}. Action: {action.span.text}")


us_30()
```

im trying to get the rsi value from the website

Error:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a requests session:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def us_30():
    session = requests.Session()
    page = session.get('https://www.investing.com/indices/us-30-technical')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    print(soup)
    summary = soup.find(id="techStudiesInnerWrap")
    print(summary.div.text)
    name = soup.find("td", class_="first left symbol", string="RSI(14)")
    value = name.find_next('td')
    action = value.find_next('td')
    print(f"Name: {name.text}. Value:{value.text}. Action: {action.span.text}")


us_30()
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html>
<head>
<title>403 You are banned from this site.  Please contact via a different client configuration if you believe that this is a mistake.</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Error 403 You are banned from this site.  Please contact via a different client configuration if you believe that this is a mistake.</h1>
<p>You are banned from this site.  Please contact via a different client configuration if you believe that this is a mistake.</p>
<h3>Guru Meditation:</h3>
<p>XID: 1557864559</p>
<hr/>
<p>Varnish cache server</p>
</body>
</html>

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "x.py", line 18, in <module>
    us_30()
  File "x.py", line 11, in us_30
    print(summary.div.text)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'div'
```

Now, you just need to figure out how not to get banned :)

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you have not defined what `session` variable is.
If you are using the `requests` module, I suppose you would have something like

```
import requests
requests.get(url)
```

Or I suppose you are using selenium session. Please correct that.

Comment: "C:\Users\Joao Fernandes\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\Scripts\python.exe" "C:/Users/Joao Fernandes/PycharmProjects/untitled/main.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Joao Fernandes/PycharmProjects/untitled/main.py", line 16, in <module>
    us_30()
  File "C:/Users/Joao Fernandes/PycharmProjects/untitled/main.py", line 9, in us_30
    print(summary.div.text)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'div'

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: @Shrutheesh Raman: Importing `requests` does not solve the issue.

Comment: @MauriceMeyer, I merely gave ```requests``` as an example. It depends on what kind of web-scraping you will be doing.

Comment: I notice that the web page you wish to scrape from has javascript embedded. So you have to get the part sorted first. You are getting ```Nonetype``` error since the data is not being downloaded correctly in the first place